# identity expired error while doing composer network ping

Tags: hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Long time back I have created a composer network by using composer version 0.19.0. Now when I am trying to ping the network using following command getting this error.

composer network ping --card admin@tutorial-network

output :Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: identity expired

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other identities registered (and thus have cards in your card store) with your business network which haven't expired ? If you don't then you are locked out of your business network. If you do but they don't have the appropriate ACLS to perform things like identity management (composer identity issue/bind etc) then so long as you have a card that doesn't have an expired identity that can perform install/upgrade you could upgrade your business network to provide required ACLs for that participant to be able to do identity management.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue today and solved like below.

First you need to delete that card using this command.

```
composer card delete
```

Then you can add a new card. (You have a .bna file at the same directory) Use this command below for importing new card.

```
composer card import --file networkadmin.card
```

You can ping successfully.

```
composer network ping --card admin@cardName
```

I hope this will solve your problem. Then you can start the rest server with below code.

```
composer-rest-server
```