# Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: identity expired

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I had created a composer network a year ago on version 0.19.6. Today when I try and start my composer rest server, I am getting the below error:

```
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Connection fails: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: identity expired
It will be retried for the next request.
Exception: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: identity expired
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: identity expired
```

I referred to response given to this question:  [identity expired error while doing composer network ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56127993/identity-expired-error-while-doing-composer-network-ping) and understood that the business network is locked. 
How do I unlock my business network when I do not have any card which is not expired?

Answer (score 0):

The details about ensuring you don't let your certificates expire is  linked here https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4652. This also provides some detail about the way the composer runtime registers identities

However if you don't have any registered identities which have not expired (ie all your registered identities have expired) then you are locked out of your business network. You must have at least 1 registered identity which has not expired to be able to interact with your business network. If you have one but it doesn't have the ability to issue new identities, you can change the ACLs (or delete the ACL file) temporarily to allow that identity more control and then upgrade to that business network (so long as you can upgrade and that identity hasn't expired) once done you can then upgrade to the previous version of the business network effectively returning to the original ACL version.

Your only solution now is to port your application off of composer see https://davidkel.github.io/docs/Porting/TOC.html as you can still access the data. It's the composer business network runtime that locks you out of the business network implementation so by porting your application you remove the composer runtime. But that also requires that you have a non expired identity that can still upgrade the chaincode.